# Gaussian convergence in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory

This is an intermediate step of prop 1.2 on p. 2 of http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mdamron6/teaching/Fall_2018/notes/Math_7244_week_1.pdf.

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n$ has $\mathcal{N}(m_n,\sigma^2_n)$ distribution.  If $X_n\rightarrow X$ in $L^2$, then $|E(X^2)-E(X_n^2)|\rightarrow 0$ due to convergence in $L^2$.  Can someone explain why this holds to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the $L^2$ convergence you have:
$$E((X_n-X)^2)^{1/2}\to 0$$

By triangular inequality:
$$ E(X_n^2)^{1/2}=E((X+(X_n-X))^2)^{1/2}\leq E(X^2)^{1/2}+E((X_n-X)^2)^{1/2}$$
$$ E(X^2)^{1/2}=E((X_n+(X-X_n))^2)^{1/2}\leq E(X_n^2)^{1/2}+E((X_n-X)^2)^{1/2}$$

Thus:
$$|E(X_n^2)^{1/2}-E(X^2)^{1/2}|\to 0$$

Hence:
$$|E(X_n^2)-E(X^2)|\to 0.$$